# Perform action on check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change this function so that it performs it after a user checks a box, instead of clicking on a button? Also, if they uncheck, another function gets executed.

```
 $("#saveData")
     .click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
     var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();
     $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
         if (obj.name != "creditCard") {
             localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
         }
     });
 });
```

Here's the input field,

```
<input id="saveAddress" type="checkbox" name="address">Save Address
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the HTML or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as an example of what you currently have?

Comment: "Also, if they uncheck, another function gets executed." And what function would that be?

Answer (score 2):

Well, with there information I have here are some basic guidlines:

```
$('#checkbox_element').change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
    //checkbox checked, do your thing
  }else{
    //it has been unchecked
  }
});
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uHEhh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Change `$("#saveData").click` to `$("#saveAddress").click`, so you get something like:

```
$("#saveAddress")
     .click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
     var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();
     $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
         if (obj.name != "creditCard") {
             localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
         }
     });
 });
```

(also you can use `$(this).(':checked')` inside the event handler to perform different actions for checking/unchecking)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
 $("#saveAddress").click(function(e) {
   if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
    var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        if(obj.name != "creditCard") {
            localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
        }
    });             
   } else {
       /*Other function code*/
   }
});
```